# Auto filtering to exclude specific month

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a loop that is deleting rows based on the month within the date

```
Dim k As Long
For k = FindLastRow(.Sheets(NewSheet)) To 2 Step -1
    If Not Month(.Sheets(NewSheet).Cells(k, 1).Value) = NewMonth Then
    .Sheets(NewSheet).Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next k
```

This is very slow and I have code that I've used elsewhere for doing this quicker, this example is based on deleting 0 values:

```
Dim rngDataBlock As Range
Set rngDataBlock = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(8, 8))
With rngDataBlock
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=0
    .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
End With
.AutoFilterMode = False
```

What I can't figure out is how to apply this to my 1st case where I'm deleting based on the month of the date. I tried:

```
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & Month(NewMonth)
```

but this doesn't work, I guess as the filter is actually loking at whole dates rather than months. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second criteria and operator parameters to delete using autofilter.

```
    Dim rngDataBlock As Range
    Set rngDataBlock = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(16, 2)) 
    With rngDataBlock
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=" & DateSerial(2021, Month(newmonth), 1), _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & DateSerial(2021, Month(newmonth) + 1, -1)

        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
```

You can also speed up your original example by unionizing the rows you want to delete and then deleting in one go.

```
 Dim k As Long
    Dim delrng As Range
    For k = FindLastRow(.Sheets(NewSheet)) To 2 Step -1
        If Not Month(.Sheets(NewSheet).Cells(k, 1).Value) = newmonth Then
            If delrng Is Nothing Then
                Set delrng = .Sheets(NewSheet).Rows(k).EntireRow
            Else
                Set delrng = Union(delrng, .Sheets(NewSheet).Rows(k).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next k
    delrng.Delete
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of using DateSerial, a pretty straightforward solution really!
Union isn't a command I'm familiar with, I'll have to experiment with it.
Thanks for the help!